# Java and SAML - where to start?

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, saml

We have a custom REST web app (Java based) that uses username/password to login. Call this application 'Admin'. The users of Admin also use a couple of commercial cloud based applications, call these App1 and App2.
What I've been asked to do is investigate how we can use single sign on between Admin, App1 and App2. App1 and App2 can be configured to use SAML and I have  full access to the code of the Admin application. I've done some preliminary reading and understand the principles involved.

I want to prototype some code but I'm not sure where to start! For example how should I proceed with the identity provider? What interface should it implement, is there an abstract class that should be extended? Similarly for the service provider. Given that App1 and App2 can be configured to use SAML what changes/extensions are needed on the Admin app?

Many Thanks
M

Comment: Have you looked at the Spring quick start guide? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html  I would download it and look at the example. Does you company have an in-house IDP, or are you looking to go with a commercial provider?  I'm not sure why your Admin app implementation would be different.  If you have no experience with this, essentially you're replacing your login page with the IDP's login page.  Download the spring extension, that has an example on how to implement it.  If you using a commercial site, they should also have a guide.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The IDP is something that we will implement as part of the overall task.  It's also the point I've taken to start from... Don't know if that is the correct decision but one has to start somewhere and getting the IDP correct will at least allow SSO from the two commercial apps.

Comment: I guess having an IDP is the place to start.  Our IDP is integrated with our LDAP, so we can do both internal and external logins, as well as social logins (gmail, facebook, linkedin, etc.).  Our security group did build some additional services around it, mainly for configuration, that allow us to modify the data returned upon authentication, like LDAP groups and memberships, permissions, etc. for continuity.  Authorization is managed separately by each of the groups using it.  We have started to look at cloud IDP providers going forward, mainly for disaster recovery and business continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of pac4j.

If you have Java apps and want to secure them using SAML, you should definitely take a look at [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org) which is a security engine available for many Java frameworks: [J2E](https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j), [Spring MVC / Boot](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j), [Play](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j) and so many more.

For SAML support: http://www.pac4j.org/1.9.x/docs/clients/saml.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Shibboleth provides both IdP and SP (implemented with OpenSAML v3) for you to test with:

- https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Installation
- https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Installation

If you want to integrate SAML into your own application in Java, there are:

- OpenSAML v3: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home
- Spring Security SAML: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/
- Spring boot Security SAML: https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample